# Python Flask SelectField on submit gives None

Tags: python, select, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a select fields in my form which I have declared as follows:

```
class WorkuploadForm(Form):
   ....
   worktype = SelectField('worktype', choices=[('', '')],
             validators=[validators.Required("Select type of work.")])
   contenttype = SelectField('contenttype', choices=[('', '')],
      validators=[validators.Required("Please select content type.")])
   ....
   submit = SubmitField('Publish')

   def validate(self):
    flash(self.worktype.choices)
    flash(self.worktype.data)
    ....
    return validate_form(self)
```

The `validate()` function in my form class has some custom validations and `validate_form()` function is wtf's default function for form validation.

I have populated choices for both the select fields from database as follows:

```
@module.route("/<penname>/workupload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@handle_error
@login_required
def workupload(penname=None, workid=None):
  workupload_form = WorkUploadForm(prefix="upload", 
                                   csrf_enabled=False)
  ...
  workupload_form.worktype.choices = getVariables("variables", "work")
  workupload_form.contenttype.choices = getVariables("variables",
                                                     "content")
  ...
```

Where, `getVariables()` is a function which reads values from database and returns as choices list.

Up to here everything works fine, I am getting list properly which I can select. The Options are as follows:

```
[('', ''), (u'story', u'Story'), (u'poem', u'Poem'), (u'book', u'Book'), (u'article', u'Article')]
```

But as soon as I submit form and `validate_on_submit()` is called, both `workupload_form.worktype.data` and `workupload_form.contenttype.data` are `None`

Why is this happening. I should get selected value here, but why it gives me None?

**NOTE:**

1. In `validate_on_submit()` when I printed choices for both `workupload_form.worktype.choices` and `workupload_form.contenttype.choices` gives me list of choices available as per database has given.
2. I added alerts in jquery to verify on submit what are values selected in each of the select fields and it gives me correct selected value.
3. I have other select fields in this form which are populated with values from database similar way and they are working fine and are having values as per selected on submit.

Comment: What types are you using in the data you are getting from the database when you are populating choices? Is it integers, strings or?

Comment: They are strings. Example like [('story', 'Story'), ('poem', 'Poem')...]